# Patching Mac DMA attack

Tags: malware, macos

I want to know a few things about the blackhat attack that attacks thunderbolt. Is there anyway to wipe or patch a currently infected computer? I am not  versed per se in THAT level of security. I was considering using veracrypt, but I understand the DMA attack works on the firmware update system, not the disk and can be used to get passwords. Can someone explain this to me? I have a late 2011 macbook pro and mac os 10.10.2 If it's possible to patch it, is there anyway to prevent it from working again? MY plan (at least so far):

Veracrypt use. I know how to use veracrypt eetc.
Possible 2fa with this? Yubikey or just a password program with yubikey.
Secure key chain access. Network etc.
 ETC ETC. 
OTher things as well that I can't think of as of this writing, because I know the restoration procedure of my computer. It takes forever.
All started from a new clean machine etc.

But what about anything else? Basically I want nothing to work except the hard disk and I want to secure the efi boot partition (And anything else) so that NOTHING WORKS (hardware or other wise) unless you open the computer or have both the firmware passcode and the hard disk passcode. I am interested in physical security as of now. Is there a solution or workaround now?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a word ... no.  These attacks bypass your OS and anything running on it.  If you are interested in physical security, you need to add hardware that protects these devices or by a secured computer.

Comment: Fundamentally, if you aren't able to secure the physical site, then expect it to get a little hoary.